# AIME 1991 Number theory Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> **Question** -
>   $[\text { AIME } 1991]$ Suppose that $r$ is a real number for which
>   $
> \left\lfloor r+\frac{19}{100}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor r+\frac{20}{100}\right\rfloor+\cdots+\left\lfloor r+\frac{91}{100}\right\rfloor=546
> $
>   Find $\lfloor 100 r\rfloor$

Now author proved using some simple techniques that

$
\left\lfloor r+\frac{56}{100}\right\rfloor=7 \quad \text {and} \quad\left\lfloor r+\frac{57}{100}\right\rfloor=8
$

It follows that $7.43 \leq r<7.44$ and hence that $\lfloor 100 r\rfloor=743$

***but i did not see how they found that $7.43 \leq r<7.44$***

Comment: It is reorganising $r+\frac{56}{100} \lt 8$ and  $r+\frac{57}{100} \ge 8$

Comment: $\lfloor r + 0.56\rfloor=7\iff 7\leq r +0.56<8$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509462/how-could-r-have-two-values

Comment: i see thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left\lfloor r+\frac{56}{100}\right\rfloor=7 \implies r+\frac{56}{100} \lt 8 \implies r < 7.44$$

$$\left\lfloor r+\frac{57}{100}\right\rfloor=8 \implies r+\frac{57}{100} \ge 8 \implies r \ge 7.43$$

Comment: There are $73$  terms in increasing order. The first $x$ of them are each $7$ and the last $73-x$ of them are each $8$, and $7x+8(73-x)=546.$